# Java. Determine two method invocations have similar thread context

Tags: java, multithreading, stack-trace

I'm trying to implement a tricky thing and need some fresh ideas.
The problem is:

Imagine Component1, that is performing some action for each User in a collection.
Just like

```
for (User user : users) {
   doSomeStuff(user);
}
```

These actions have some common parts, that are time-consuming, so the goal is to perform them only once (they include some database queries and so on).

Imagine one of this time consuming methods:

```
public Object buildSomething(Object context) {
// some business logic here
}
```

The idea was to store the result and share it for other users, like this

```
public Object buildSomething(Object context) {
    if (sharedResource.contains('something') {
        return sharedResource.get('something');
    } else {
    // some business logic here
        sharedResource.put('something', something)
        return something;
    }        
}
```

The riddle is - how to implement this shared resource?

Must say, this is a huge multi layer web application and we can't just change doSomeStuff method and add a context holder parameter there, or something similar.

I analyzed the following variants:

- Session scope bean (the one that makes the buildSomething stuff)

  Problems: User can logout from application, login  with another username/pass, he will still have same Http session and that means he will get the same bean with previous request state

  upd: Another problem of using session scope is spring based thread pool scheduler, that can invoke Component1 without any http session.
- ThreadLocal variable

  Problems: We are in a web application context, and when thread is returned to pool, it can be used for other user requests

**I tried to find a workaround for second problem and my question is:**

**Is it possible to analyze stack trace elements and ensure, that two invocations of buildSomething method were caused by a single user request?**

Tx for attention

Comment: And what is wrong with a `ThreadLocal` you should ensure that you always cleanup the thread local after your request (or scheduler) finishes. Both Java itself and Spring rely on `ThreadLocals` for a lot of things like transaction management, connection handling, open session in view etc….

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I decided to post my solution to this problem, that now works on production server.

It is based on a ThreadLocal variable, that holds the information in a request scope.

The original problem was in a fact, that different clients can reuse a single thread, because threads are stored in a pool. This fact didn't allow to use session beans and thread locals as is.

So I had to review all entry points, where user requests come to my application layer. When I detected a request, I cleaned thread local context for a request. It worked, because there are only few ways for request to come to application layer: it could be a service request from another layer, that could be intercepted with AOP and a scheduler job, that can be intercepted by custom ThreadPoolExecutor.

Answer (score 0):

I think session scoped beans are the better solution. You can manage when a session is destroyed or created. You need to call "HttpSession.invalidate()" when a user logs out.

There is a good article about session lifecycle management.
http://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/java-ent/servlet/ch07_05.htm

You also can use the HttpSession utils to store information in session (such as username).

Salut!

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I will edit the question to clarify some more problems of session scope use : there is a spring based pool scheduler in our application, that can call Component1 method, in this case we will not have any session at all. The second problem is that my problem is not big enough to change exist session management in application.